# <xsl:if test> not working as expected

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT. I have the following XML I'm trying to extract strings from. But I have to make sure there are no empty strings since the receiving application doesn't allow for empty fields. So in the case where the source XML has no value in the description field that carries the role attribute "descRole:audio" and is next to the sibling node 'itemClass' that has the role attribute of qcode="icls:video", I want to insert a whitespace character.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<newsMessage xmlns="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/">
    <itemSet>
        <packageItem>
            <itemMeta/>
            <contentMeta/>
        </packageItem>
        <newsItem>
            <itemMeta>
                <itemClass qcode="icls:text"/>
            </itemMeta>
            <contentMeta>
                <description role="descRole:intro" xml:lang="en"></description>                
                <description role="descRole:moreInfo" xml:lang="en"></description>
            </contentMeta>
        </newsItem>
        <newsItem>
            <itemMeta>
                <itemClass qcode="icls:video"/>
            </itemMeta>
            <contentMeta>
                <description role="descRole:audio" xml:lang="en">NATURAL</description>
            </contentMeta>
        </newsItem>
    </itemSet>
</newsMessage>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:d="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/d:newsMessage[1]/d:itemSet[1]/d:newsItem[d:itemMeta/d:itemClass/@qcode='icls:video']/d:contentMeta/d:description[@role='descRole:audio']"/>
<xsl:if test=".=''"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Somehow this isn't working for me and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xsl:if` is unrelated to the `xsl:value-of` statement that proceeds it...

```
<xsl:if test=".=''"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
```

In this case, the `.` simply refers to the current context node, which is the document node being matched by the template, so the value of your `xsl:value-of` is not relevant.

Try using a variable in this case:

```
<xsl:variable name="value" select="/d:newsMessage[1]/d:itemSet[1]/d:newsItem[d:itemMeta/d:itemClass/@qcode='icls:video']/d:contentMeta/d:description[@role='descRole:audio']"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$value" />
<xsl:if test="$value=''"> </xsl:if>
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks for the explanation, now this all makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform an XML document with most parts unchanged, but some parts transformed then start with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then add templates with match patterns for those elements that need a change e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="d:newsMessage[1]/d:itemSet[1]/d:newsItem[d:itemMeta/d:itemClass/@qcode='icls:video']/d:contentMeta/d:description[@role='descRole:audio'][. = '']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```